# Adding Confidence Intervals in Pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I am using pgfplots to generate the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$]
    \addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] plot coordinates {
        (0,2)
        (2,3)
        (3,1)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Case 1}

    \addplot[smooth,color=red,mark=x]
        plot coordinates {
            (0,0)
            (1,1)
            (2,1)
            (3,2)
        };
    \addlegendentry{Case 2}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Does anyone know how it is possible to add confidence intervals to each of the plotted points?

Cheers, Mil

Comment: Do you have the confidence intervals for each point explicitly, or do you want it to be something like `\pm 25%`?

Comment: I have them explicitly, e.g. for (2,3) I have the CI 2-4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the error bars facility of `pgfplots` - see page 261 of the v1.10 manual. You need the keys `y dir=both`, `y explicit` and the CI is specified on each point with the positive error after `+=` and the negative error after `-=`. Note that the errors are specified as `(x,y)` after the `+=` or `-=`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

% \usepackage{tikz} <-- pgfplots loads TiKZ
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
    ]
    \addplot[
        smooth,
        mark=*,
        blue,
        error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit,
    ] plot coordinates {
        (0,2)
        (2,3) +=(0,4) -= (0,2)
        (3,1)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Case 1}

    \addplot[smooth,color=red,mark=x]
        plot coordinates {
            (0,0)
            (1,1)
            (2,1)
            (3,2)
        };
    \addlegendentry{Case 2}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: cool. what if I want to plot from a table?

Comment: @HughPerkins maybe your are looking for something like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397190/tikzpicture-error-bars